# Python Regular Expression Define Start End

Tags: python, regex

How would I use regular expression to find only links that end with numbers

i've tried:

```
links = "'http://www.badlink.com' , 'http://good.link.com/W0QQAdIdZ567296978'"  
re.findall(r'http://[\w\.\w\.\w\.-]+.*',links)
```

I don't know how to make python stop searching after it finds integers in the link.
Best case scenario I would like the match to only occur if the link ends with (5) or more numbers

Comment: `https?://(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z.-]+/\w*\d{5,}`

Comment: Why do you use findall? findall does not get list as its input https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.findall

Comment: I used findall because im searching a large str format txt file for links and i'm new to python also.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
re.findall(r'^http://.+?\d{5,}$',links)
```

Visual explanation:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7nMmdOfaG9JAK6a-)

Answer (score 1):

If a single number at the end is good enough:

```
 good_links = filter(lambda x: x.startswith("http://") and 
               all(c in "0123456789" for c in x[-4:]), links.split("'"))
```

Comment: no it would have to be 4 or more because their may be a digit in the link.

Comment: your answer is more simplistic, but i need to to only find links starting with http:// and ending with 4 digits.